# In the PrivateKey sign() method why are s and N-s equivalent solutions?

Tags: signature, secp256k1, programming-bitcoin-book

In the PrivateKey sign() method (Chapter 3 page 70) s is calculated like this

```
# s = (z + re)/k
s = (z + r * self.secret) * k_inv % N 
if s > N / 2:
   s = N - s
```

Why does s and N - s work?

Closest I can get is (page 76) "if we know x, we know the y coordinate has to be either y or p - y", but s is not a y co-ordinate, merely the result of integer arithmetic, there's no elliptic curve math here. Is it purely a property of a prime order field (group)? In the book it's treated as something that should be obvious so perhaps I missed something or am not seeing a connection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verification equation for ECDSA is

```
X coordinate of ((z/s)G + (r/s)Q) mod n = r
```

Where the divisions happen modulo the order of the curve (*n*), and *z* is the message hash (taken modulo *n* again). Also, while the X coordinate that comes out is a number in the field *GF(p)* (not *GF(n)*), it is interpreted as an integer, and then taken modulo *n* before comparison with *r*.

If it so happens that you have a pair *(r, s)* that satisfies this equation, then substituting *-s* (which equals *n-s* modulo *n*) gives:

```
   ( (z/(-s))G +  (r/(-s))Q)
```

Due to the fact that in elliptic curve multiplication it holds that `(-a)P = -(aP)` (where the first `-` is an integer negation modulo `n`, and the second `-` is elliptic curve point negation), it follows that:

```
=  (-(z/  s) G + -(r/  s )Q)
= -( (z/  s) G +  (r/  s )Q)
```

In other words, the result is the (point) negation of the `((z/s)G + (r/s)Q)` that appears in the normal formula. Negating an elliptic curve point only changes its Y coordinate, not its X coordinate, so the result will have the same X coordinate, `r`, and thus the verification equation will also succeed for the signature with negated `s`.

Note that in Bitcoin there is a policy rule that every `s` needs to be between `0` and `n/2`, disallowing one of the two variants.

Comment: OK, got it. Nice clear explanation, thank you :-)

My confusion stemmed from me trying to get from the expression in the prior line (z + re)/k which are all integers, to a value that was being treated like two y-coordinates s and N-s.

Cheers.